# How can I determine where mobs will spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been putting torches all over the place, but I'm not sure if I have enough light to prevent monsters from spawning.

How can I figure out if something will spawn in a certain location?

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature of [Not Enough Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-147152-smp-chickenbones-mods/) (NEI) as of version 1.4.7.0. A red grid showing blocks mobs can spawn on can be toggled on and off with <kbd>F7</kbd> (by default; I like to rebind it to <kbd>L</kbd> for easier access).

Answer (score 1):

The best mod that does this is called **Monster Spawn Highlighter** made by Lunatrius.

You can find it [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1296949-146-lunatrius-mods/)

Usage is simple. Hit L, click on mobs to select those you want highlighted and select the type of highlight (bottom left). Finally click Done.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for Safe a.k.a "Critter Spawn Highlighter".

Comment: Safe appears to only be available as part of [Zombe's Modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-146-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v681-upd-04jan/). Do you know if a stand-alone version of the mod exists?

Comment: I do not know of any stand-alone mods right now but each mod in the mod-pack can be individually enabled or disabled which could achieve the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

[SpawnChecker](https://github.com/alalwww/SpawnChecker) is a good alternative mod made by Japanese modder.

[Mod spotlight on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M52A3joktfM)

Use Ctrl+Up/Down to switch between:

- Spawnable point checker
- Slime chunk finder
- Spawner visualizer

Up/Down to switch between display options

[Num+]/[Num-] to change horizontal range
Shift+[Num+]/[Num-] to change vertical range
Ctrl+[Num+]/[Num-] to change marker brightness